# gcc: reference parameter change when using the same var on the same instruction

Tags: c++, gcc

I have pointing out a strange gcc behavior:
When the same variable is used on the same instruction, and when this variable is modified by one function call (variable passed by reference or pointer), the variable change is not modified for others function of the same instruction.

Is it a normal c++ behavior or a boggus ?
Note: Optimization (-O) flag is not set.
Note2: this work fine with solaris CC compiler.

Demonstration with gcc 4.5.3 (on linux or mingw/cygwin)

```
class C {
public:
  const C & inc(int & i) const       
  {
     ++i;
     cout << "inc: i = " << i << endl; return *this;
  }
  const C & see(int i) const   
  {     
     cout << "see: i = " << i << endl; return *this; 
  }
  const C & see2(const int & i) const {  
    cout << "see2: i = " << i << endl; return *this; }
  };

int main()
{
  C c;
  int i = 0;
  c.see(i).inc(i).see(i).see2(i).inc(i).see(i).see2(i);
  c.see(i);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> see: i = 0
>   inc: i = 1
>   see: i = 0 **: 1 expected**
>   see2: i = 1
>   inc: i = 2
>   see: i = 0 **: 2 expected**
>   see2: i = 2
>   see: i = 2

Answer (score 2):

The order of evaluation of function arguments is indeterminate with respect to each other.  In this case gcc has chosen to evaluate `i` as passed to the `see` method calls early.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
class C {};
C &inc(C &c, int &i) { ++i; return c; }
C &see(C &c, int i) { std::cout << i << '\n'; return c; }
C c;
int i = 0;
see(inc(c, i), i);
```

Valid evaluation orders of the arguments of `see` are:

```
1. evaluate inc(...) to pass c to see(...)
2. evaluate i as an rvalue to pass to see(...)

1. evaluate i as an rvalue to pass to see(...)
2. evaluate inc(...) to pass c to see(...)
```

In the former case the program prints `1`; in the latter it prints `0`.

Note that behaviour is *unspecified* but not *undefined*; it must print either `0` or `1`.  This is because a sequence point obtains before and after the call to `inc`; in C++11, the execution of a function is indeterminately sequenced (but not unsequenced) with respect to evaluations in the calling function (1.9p15).

Comment: @user1863135 if you're questioning the different behaviour of `see2`, that's because the argument is a (const) reference, so the value computation (i.e. reading the value of `i`) occurs inside the function, not in its argument list.

Comment: Then `see(inc(c, i), i)` is different to `const C & x = inc(c, i); see(x, i);`
For me the former case is a shortcut for the latter. But I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behaviour: It is not specified by the standard, in which order subexpressions of a given statement are executed. In your case obviously the compiler first executes all the `i` subexpressions, i.e. makes the copies of `i` to pass them to the different calls of `see()`, *before* any call to `inc()` gets evaluated.